# Location of android's device manufacturer's keystore file?

Tags: android, keystore, bootloader

How can we sign android apks with the same keys used by device manufacturer? In other words, what is the location of manufacturer's keystore file

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, what is the location of manufacturer's keystore file

The location of their keystore file is in their company headquarters. Obtaining this keystore file will probably involve violating various local laws.

> How can we sign android apks with the same keys used by device manufacturer?

You work for the manufacturer, or you are hired by the manufacturer to write an app which they then sign.